# Split String in Half By Word

Tags: javascript

I'm in a situation where I'd like to take a string and split it in half, respecting words so that `this string here` doesn't get split into `this str` `ing here`, rather it would be split into `this string` `here`.

I figure a starting step would to be to split the string into an array based on spaces, then calculate length based on those pieces, but in my attempts longer strings end up being split up incorrectly.

Comment: Show us your attempts, please!

Comment: @Bergi I actually answered posted this question after figuring out how to do it.  My initial attempts' bugs had to do with not adding the removed spaces when checking the word array.  My working answer is below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look for the first space before and after the middle, and pick the one closest to the middle.

Example:

```
var s = "This is a long string";

var middle = Math.floor(s.length / 2);
var before = s.lastIndexOf(' ', middle);
var after = s.indexOf(' ', middle + 1);

if (middle - before < after - middle) {
    middle = before;
} else {
    middle = after;
}

var s1 = s.substr(0, middle);
var s2 = s.substr(middle + 1);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7RNBu/

(This code assumes that there actually are spaces on both sides of the middle. You would also add checks for `before` and `after` being `-1`.)

#### Edit:

The check that I talked about in the node would be done correctly like this:

```
if (before == -1 || (after != -1 && middle - before >= after - middle)) {
    middle = after;
} else {
    middle = before;
}
```

Here is a fiddle where you can edit the text and see the result immediately: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/7RNBu/11/

Comment: Very nice!  A much better solution than mine I think.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to leave this as a comment but do not have enough rep points. The top solution right now fails pretty easily because it does not check for "-1" when using the indexOf method. See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7RNBu/7/

```
var s = "This is a long strinjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjg";
var middle = Math.floor(s.length / 2);
var before = s.lastIndexOf(' ', middle);
var after = s.indexOf(' ', middle + 1);

if (middle - before < after - middle) {
    middle = before;
} else {
    middle = after;
}

var s1 = s.substr(0, middle);
var s2 = s.substr(middle + 1);
```

Comment: Well here's some free rep.  It really doesn't matter if it hits -1 with the indexOf call actually.  Only two edge cases I could see are either having the string be blank or have no spaces.  Either way you get the string back ("" or "aaaa") in `s1`.

Comment: Thank you for the rep Dropped.on.Caprica. I'm a bit confused then, if the -1 with indexOf doesn't matter then why does the example I provided fail?

Comment: Haha, I'm dumb (and didn't actually run your code like an idiot).  Good catch!  Give me a few hours and I'll have time to come up with a fix; it really shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Good job, totally works!  Throw that up there as the answer and I'll accept it.  I don't think the 271k rep guy would mind.  :P

Comment: Just posted. Thanks Dropped.On.Caprica, I could certainly use the rep points :)

Answer (score 2):

```
let str = 'qwerty';
let half = Math.floor(str.length / 2);
str = str.slice(0, half) + ' ' + str.slice(half, str.length);

//output
'qwe rty'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also care about newlines, tabs, as well as spaces, so I would use a regex like this:

```
var s = "this string here";
var idx = s.length / 2;


while (idx < s.length && s[idx].match(/\s/) == null)
    idx++;

var s1 = s.substring(0, idx);
var s2 = s.substring(idx);

document.getElementById("s1").innerText = s1;
document.getElementById("s2").innerText = s2;
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nS6Bj/5/

Comment: Your example didn't seem to work with newlines or tabs when trying it in jsFiddle.  I think if you would need to support splitting on newlines and tabs, you could alter the @Guffa's answer to accept an argument of accepted delimiters.  You'd have a delimiter specific before and after variable, just would have to take the closest before and after var and split based on that.

Comment: My comment made much more sense in my head.  I can show you an example if you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I first thought I had an off-by-one error, but I eventually worked through it.  [Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/droppedonjapan/Pu9NT/1/)

Now to break down the logic used:

```
var calculate = function(initialString) {
  var halfwayPoint = Math.floor(initialString.length / 2);
  var strArray = initialString.split(' ');
  // Caluclate halfway point, then break string into words

  var wordFlag;  // Will be split point
  var charCount = 0;
  _.each( strArray, function(word, strArrayIndex) {
    if (wordFlag) return false;
    // If we have the location, exit

    // If charCount is before the halfway point
    // and the end of word is after halfway point
    // Then set the flag
    // We add strArrayIndex to the word length to include spaces
    if (charCount <= halfwayPoint && 
      ((charCount + word.length + strArrayIndex) >= halfwayPoint) ) {
      wordFlag = strArrayIndex;
      return false;
    }

    // Increase charCount to be length at the end of this word
    charCount += (word.length);
  });

  if (!wordFlag) return null;

  // Split the word array by the flag we figured out earlier
  var lineOneArray = strArray.slice(0, (wordFlag + 1));
  var lineTwoArray = strArray.slice(wordFlag + 1);


  // We now join the word arrays into a string, stripping beginning and ending spaces.
  var stOne = (lineOneArray.join(' ')).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
  var stTwo = (lineTwoArray.join(' ')).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

  // Finally return the split strings as an array.
  return [stOne, stTwo];
};
```

If anyone sees holes in my logic, let me know! I'm pretty sure this works in most cases though.

If you'd like the second string to be longer than the first, (ie have the line break before rather than after the middle word), then don't add +1 to wordFlag.

Answer (score 0):

This will split your string based on word count (not character count, so the exact length of each half could be quite different, depending on the placement of long & short words).

```
var s = "This is a string of filler text";

var pieces = s.split(" "),
    firstHalfLength = Math.round(pieces.length/2),
    str1 = "",
    str2 = "";

for (var i = 0; i < firstHalfLength; i++){
    str1 += (i!=0?" ":"") + pieces[i];
}
for (var i = firstHalfLength; i < pieces.length; i++){
    str2 += (i!=firstHalfLength?" ":"") + pieces[i];
}

document.write(s);
document.write("<br />"+str1);
document.write("<br />"+str2);

// Output
This is a string of filler text
This is a string
of filler text
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/7RNBu/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
         <h1>
              <span>
                // for first half start from 0 till middle
                {title.substring(0, title.length / 2)}
              </span>
              <span>
                // second half just point the starting point
                {title.substring(title.length / 2)}
              </span>
         </h1>
```