# Fit text to a specific number of lines, variable width

Tags: css

My page displays a set of news items, each with a headline. The headline can be a variable number of words, but I’d like them to always be on two lines with as balanced widths as possible. For example:

```
Announcing Bosun, our new open
source monitoring & alerting system

Stack Exchange for
the iPad is here

A
headline
```

Obviously I could chuck in a `<br>` element at the correct break point and I could even try to calculate its position automatically, but is there any CSS that will do this for me? It’d be nice to get this working in a responsive layout. I don’t care particularly about browser compatibility so answers that reference upcoming specs that achieve what I want will be accepted too.

Comment: This would probably be far easier to do with JavaScript than CSS.

Comment: Since headlines likely won't carry a fixed range of characters for it's length, @j08691 is right that JavaScript would take care of this for you better than CSS on its own would.

Comment: Yep, and I will if I need to, I just thought someone might have a cunning trick I’d missed.

Comment: I can't think of any way of doing this with CSS. Everything you need to accomplish this with Javascript is in this great answer from @Guffa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087416/split-string-in-half-by-word

Comment: Thanks Moobs, that’s a great fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there’s no way of doing this in CSS currently, but CSS4 Text has just added `text-wrap: balance` to the draft specification which does exactly what my question asked for. I’ll leave this as the answer for the glorious future where this is supported.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-4/#text-wrap

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
div {   
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 165px; // define max width of the text
    height: 30px;     // define height of the text based on font size and line height
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 11px;    
}
```

Plus to make it fancy you can try to add ellipsis (...) to the end of the bottom line:

```
div {   
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 165px; // define max width of the text
    height: 30px;     // define height of the text based on font size and line height
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 11px;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but that won’t ‘balance’ the text on both lines (something that I guess I didn’t make clear in the original question, I’ll go and revise it).

Comment: No, it won't indeed :) Perhaps css's `calc` would do the trick if used properly?